# RecylerView is not shoing up in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my fragment recyclerview is not showing up . when i tried in my activity its populating the results as expected but in my fragment when i initiate the recyclerview its not showing up its blank .
Yes have getItemCount in my adapter (already it is working in othr activity with the same adapter)
My Fragment initialization

```
      public static ProfileSearchFragment newInstance(String searchText,String algoliaKey, String applicationId) {
    ProfileSearchFragment fragment = new ProfileSearchFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(SearchText, searchText);
    args.putString(AlgoliaKey, algoliaKey);
    args.putString(ApplicationId, applicationId);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mSearchText = getArguments().getString(SearchText);
        mAlgoliaKey = getArguments().getString(AlgoliaKey);
        mApplicationId = getArguments().getString(ApplicationId);

    }
}
```

Have tried both in onCreateView and in onViewCreated:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_search, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_search_recyclerview);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: getting the Searchtext hopefully  " + mSearchText + ":" + mAlgoliaKey);

    mUserImage = new ArrayList<>();
    mUserName = new ArrayList<>();
    mUserId = new ArrayList<>();


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    userSearchAdapter = new UserSearchAdapter(getContext(),mUserImage,mUserName,mUserId);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(userSearchAdapter);


    final Client client = new Client(mApplicationId, mAlgoliaKey);
    final Index index = client.getIndex("Users");

    if (mSearchText!=null){
        Query query = new Query(mSearchText)
                .setAttributesToRetrieve("user_username", "user_image_url", "user_id")
                .setHitsPerPage(50);
        index.searchAsync(query, new CompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void requestCompleted(JSONObject content, AlgoliaException error) {
                try {
                    JSONArray hits = content.getJSONArray("hits");
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < hits.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = hits.getJSONObject(i);
                        mUserName.add(jsonObject.getString("user_username"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "requestCompleted: Userrrrr: " + jsonObject.getString("user_username"));
                        mUserImage.add(jsonObject.getString("user_image_url"));
                        mUserId.add(jsonObject.getString("user_id"));

                        Log.d(TAG, "requestCompleted: Size: " + mUserImage.size());
                        userSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

When i log i get size of the array as well as populating the array with values;

In my main activity i am using a viewpager2 to set up my fragment

```
      private void setUpViewPager(){
    SectionPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(this);

    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileSearchFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new TemplateSearchTagsFragment());
    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.search_viewpager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

}

  @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            ProfileSearchFragment fragment = ProfileSearchFragment.newInstance(editable.toString(),algoliaKey,applicationId);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.add(fragment,"profile_search_fragment").commit();

           
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me to point the mistake .thanks!

My Adapter:

```
  public class UserSearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserSearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "UserSearchAdapter";
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> mUserImage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mUserName = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mUserId = new ArrayList<>();

public UserSearchAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String>
        mUserImage, ArrayList<String> mUserName, ArrayList<String> mUserId) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mUserImage = mUserImage;
    this.mUserName = mUserName;
    this.mUserId = mUserId;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);
    SearchViewHolder holder = new SearchViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mUserImage.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
            .into(holder.image_profile);

    holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.username.setText(mUserName.get(position));
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUserName.size();
}

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView username,fullname;
    private CircleImageView image_profile;
    private Button btn_follow;

    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        btn_follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
    }
}
```

My log prints:

2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Size: 1

2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Userrrrr: Algolia2
2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Size: 2

2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Userrrrr: giraffee
2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Size: 3

2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Userrrrr: zumba
2020-06-26 17:56:36.014 3620-3620/com.shivaconsulting.memesapp D/ProfileSearchFragment: requestCompleted: Size: 4

[image: my log and debug]

Comment: So... where item list is your recycler adapter using? Why not post it's code? does the request actually complete?

Comment: @Shark i thought it would be vague adding the adapter's code ..sorry for not posting the question briefly have edited my question and added the adapter code

Comment: this log prints, right? `Log.d(TAG, "requestCompleted: Size: " + mUserImage.size());`

what happens when you set a breakpoint on the `notifyDataSetChanged()` and inspect the three lists in the adapter? are they non-empty?

Comment: yes those are log prints its size of the array have attached the screenshot for more clarification

Comment: soooo.... it seems like everything is working? could it be that it's some stupid XML problem that's clipping/cutting off the recyclerview from showing?

Comment: 1) Have you tried setting a breakpoint in onBindViewHolder? 2) Have you inspected your layout using Layout Inspector option in Android Studio? Your RV might be obscured by some other view at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the RV adapter with empty Array lists and later when you get the data in callback method

> requestCompleted

You are not setting the data to the adapter.

There should be a method in the RV adapter like

```
userSearchAdapter.updateData(<updated data>)
```

Then you call notifyDataSetChanged

```
userSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the adapter

Comment: Thanks will give a try 

Comment: Another way is to call notifyDataSetChanged() inside the updateData(<updated data>) method itself

Answer (score 0):

Please check your adapter implementation. `userSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is being called multiple times inside the for loop. Please move it outside of your for loop. Once your dataset is ready. Update the adapter and then notify the change. Currently, you have just created an empty `list`. You are not using it anywhere. If I have understood correctly, you are going to fill this list with required item and pass it to the adapter for display.

Comment: have tried moving the userSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); outside the loop but still not populating . i don't have any adapter implementation i am just sending a edittext from my mainactivity to fragment